# PostgreSQL remove numbers before first comma

Tags: postgresql, update

I am new to SQL however, I am looking to update a table where column called "scrap_value" and rows contains a set of numbers in an array e.g.
`{100000,125000,150000,175000,200000}`

I want to remove the first number and comma of all rows in "scrap_value", so the end result looks like this
`{125000,150000,175000,200000}`

How would I got about doing this?

Comment: Provide table's DDL (as CREATE TABLE) and a couple of records (as INSERT INTO).

Comment: Is scrap_value a string? Or an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like an array. If that is the case, you can remove the first element of the array using an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
  scrap_value = scrap_value[2:];
```

`[2:]` selects all elements of the array starting with the second. The result of that is then used to override the existing array.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I am still learning. Yes, it is in fact an array. I will try out your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm. This worked flawlessly for me. Thanks

Comment: misses definitly the advice to overwork and normalize the data .. its usually a hint to bad design having multiple values in a single cell - array or not

Answer (score 2):

> column called "scrap_value" ... contains a set of numbers e.g. {100000,125000,150000,175000,200000}

Whilst many DBMSs will support this sort of thing, it breaks basic **Database Normalisation** rules and, since you say you're just starting out with this sort of thing, let's set you on the Right Road to being with:

These values should be split out into a separate table containing the key of the original table, plus the new value, one per row.   This makes it *very easy* to remove an item, using only a standard Delete statement:

```
select * from scraps; 
+-----------+--------+
| parent_id | value  | 
+-----------+--------+
|    123456 | 100000 | 
|    123456 | 125000 | 
|    123456 | 150000 | 
|    123456 | 175000 | 
|    123456 | 200000 | 
+-----------+--------+

delete 
from scraps 
where id = 123456 
and value = 175000 ;  

select * from scraps; 
+-----------+--------+
| parent_id | value  | 
+-----------+--------+
|    123456 | 100000 | 
|    123456 | 125000 | 
|    123456 | 150000 | 
|    123456 | 200000 | 
+-----------+--------+
```

This also makes it far, *far* easier to search for scrap values.

If you keep to the current "Lots-of-Values-all-Smooshed-Together" model, you have to do all sorts of weird, String manipulation to find an item that might be at the *start* of the string, or somewhere in the *middle* or at the *end*, all with different delimiters before and after the thing you're looking for.  Yuck!.

Using the properly normalised structure, you can just use a standard where clause :

```
select * 
from scraps 
where parent_id = 123456
and value = '150000 ; 

select * 
from scraps; 

+-----------+--------+
| parent_id | value  | 
+-----------+--------+
|    123456 | 150000 | 
+-----------+--------+
```

To match more than scrap, things get a little more exciting:

```
select * 
from scraps
where parent_id = 123456 
and value in ( 100000, 200000 ); 

+-----------+--------+
| parent_id | value  | 
+-----------+--------+
|    123456 | 200000 | 
|    123456 | 100000 | 
+-----------+--------+
```

Regards,   Phill  W.

Comment: in fact I wanted to assign +10 rating ...
Array or not .. its obviously a m:n relation put in a single column / table ... those are to be split into separate tables to have 1:m , 1:n relations